# error with matching functions c++

Tags: c++, function, match

I'm getting this error:

```
Lista.h: In instantiation of 'Lista<X>::Lista(const Lista<X>&) [with X = ArbolN<int>]': main.cpp:22:20:   required from here 
Lista.h:50:5: error: no matching function for call to 'ArbolN<int>::ArbolN(ArbolN<int>)'
l = new Nodo<X> (list.l->getInfo(), NULL);
        ^
```

With this code:

```
  #include <iostream>
#include "ArbolN.h"


using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Lista<ArbolN<int> > L;
    ArbolN<int> A(1), B(2);
    ArbolN<int> C(3);



    L.insertar( 1 , A);
    L.insertar( 2 , B);
    L.insertar( 3 , C);


    ArbolN<int> D(5, L); //this is main.cpp: 22

}
```

//first parameter is value of the root,second list with sons

```
//constructor
template <class X>
ArbolN<X>::ArbolN(X e,Lista<ArbolN<X> > h){
NodoAr<X> *aux;


    raiz= new NodoAr<X>(e);

    if(!h.esVacia()){
        //tmp = new NodoAr<X>(l.consultar(1));
        copiarNodos(h.consultar(1).raiz,raiz->HijI);
        h.eliminar(1);
        aux=raiz->HijI;

        while(!h.esVacia()){
            copiarNodos(h.consultar(1).raiz,aux->HerD);
            h.eliminar(1);
            aux=aux->HerD;
        }//while
    }//if
}



//copy constructor
//constructor copia
template <class X>
ArbolN<X>::ArbolN(ArbolN<X> &Ar){

    if(Ar.raiz){
        copiarNodos(Ar.raiz,raiz);
    }else{
        raiz=NULL;
    }
}

template <class X>
void ArbolN<X>::copiarNodos(NodoAr<X> *orig,NodoAr<X> *&dest){
NodoAr<X> *a(NULL),*b(NULL);

    if (orig != NULL){  
        dest=new NodoAr<X>(orig->info);
        copiarNodos(orig->HijI,dest->HijI);
        if((orig->HerD==NULL)&&(orig->HijI!=NULL)){
                a=orig->HijI;
                b=dest->HijI;
        }else{
            a=orig;
            b=dest;
        }

        while(a!=NULL){
            a=a->HerD;
            copiarNodos(a,b->HerD);
            b=b->HerD;
        }
    }
    else dest = NULL;
}
```

can someone tell me what im doing wrong, i have no idea why lista.h is being required in that part of the code

Comment: How should we know?  Do you don't show the header file.

Comment: It would appear that the copy constructor of `Lista` is unable to find a copy constructor for `ArbolN`.  As to what this has to do with `Nodo` or your code, I have no idea.  Show us `ArbolN`.  I'd guess it doesn't have the correct copy constructor

Comment: added, but i dont get why it goes to lista, i dont want to create a copy of L, i want to create a tree using L

Comment: I think Lista<ArbolN<int> > L; will can the constructor of Lista

Comment: @remyabel and michaeltang line 22 of main.cpp